# Scope of undefined in 2nd round of a Javascript & JQuery Trivia game

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

My game works until summary page start link is clicked. Then I get undefined variables when trying to play again.

I'm new to JS so I'm sure it is a stupid user error and not handling scope correctly.

If I comment the `location.reload` at the bottom of the javascript it works just fine after the timer is up, but the coding assignment wants us to not do a refresh. I appreciate any help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var correctAnswers = 0;
  var incorrectAnswers = 0;
  var unansweredQuestions = 0;
  var timeRemaining = 16;
  var intervalID;
  var indexQandA = 0;
  var answered = false;
  var correct;

  var start = $(".start").html("Start Game");
  start.on("click", startGame);

  var triviaQandA = [{
    question: "What is the fastest animal?",
    answer: ["cheetah", "turtle", "giraffe", "elephant"],
    correct: "0",
    image: ("assets/images/circle.png")
  }, {
    question: "When you are blue you turn?",
    answer: ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"],
    correct: "2",
    image: ("assets/images/dot.jpg")
  }];

  function startGame() {
    $(".start").hide();
    correctAnswers = 0;
    incorrectAnswers = 0;
    unansweredQuestions = 0;
    loadQandA();
  }

  function loadQandA() {
    answered = false;
    timeRemaining = 16;
    intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    if (answered === false) {
      timer();
    }

    correct = triviaQandA[indexQandA].correct;
    var question = triviaQandA[indexQandA].question;
    $(".question").html(question);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var answer = triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[i];
      $(".answers").append("<h4 class = answersAll id =" + i + ">" + answer + "</h4>");
    }

    $("h4").click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      if (id === correct) {
        answered = true;
        $(".question").text("The answer is: " + triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
        correctAnswer();
      } else {
        answered = true;
        $(".question").text("You chose: " + triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[id] + "    the correct answer is: " + triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
        incorrectAnswer();
      }
      console.log(correct);
    });
  }

  function timer() {
    if (timeRemaining === 0) {
      answered = true;
      clearInterval(intervalID);
      $(".question").text("The correct answer is: " + triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
      unAnswered();
    } else if (answered === true) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    } else {
      timeRemaining--;
      $(".timeRemaining").text("You have " + timeRemaining);
    }
  }

  function correctAnswer() {
    correctAnswers++;
    $(".timeRemaining").text("You are spot on!!!").css({
      "color": "#3d414f"
    });
    reset();
  }

  function incorrectAnswer() {
    incorrectAnswers++;
    $(".timeRemaining").text("You are sooo wrong").css({
      "color": "#3d414f"
    });
    reset();
  }

  function unAnswered() {
    unansweredQuestions++;
    $(".timeRemaining").text("You didn't choose anything...").css({
      "color": "#3d414f"
    });
    reset();
  }

  function reset() {
    $(".answersAll").remove();
    $(".answers").append("<img class=answerImage width='150' height='150' src='" + triviaQandA[indexQandA].image + "'>");
    indexQandA++;
    if (indexQandA < triviaQandA.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        loadQandA();
        $(".answerImage").remove();
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".question").remove();
        $(".timeRemaining").remove();
        $(".answerImage").remove();
        $(".answers").append("<h4 class = answersAll end>Correct answers: " + correctAnswers + "</h4>");
        $(".answers").append("<h4 class = answersAll end>Wrong answers: " + incorrectAnswers + "</h4>");
        $(".answers").append("<h4 class = answersAll end>Unanswered questions: " + unansweredQuestions + "</h4>");
        correctAnswers = 0;
        incorrectAnswers = 0;
        unansweredQuestions = 0;
        // setTimeout(function() {
        //     location.reload();
        // }, 5000);

        var start = $(".start-over").html("Start Game");
        start.on("click", startGame);
      }, 2000);
    }
  };


});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="start"></div>
<h1>Trivia</h1>
<h5 class="timeRemaining"></h5>
<h3 class="question"></h3>
<div class="answers"></div>
<div class="start-over"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's an inline link to my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/goatfeatherfarm/pen/RdNKxW).

Comment: Rory, thanks for cleaning up my first post!!!  Will do more reading on how to properly post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you increment `indexQandA` on each question, but never reset it. You need to reset it to 0 when starting a new game - that is, in the `else` clause of the `reset` function you need to put `indexQandA=0` alongside where you reset the other variables to 0.

There is a further problem when this is done though, the quiz runs ok a second time now, but doesn't display the questions any more. That's because you've removed the `.question` element during `reset`. You don't need to do this, you can just hide it, then display it again when the game restarts.

Actually, it transpired there were further problems. I've solved it - run through the game about 5 times in a row with no obvious problems - with the following code (I make no claim that this is the correct code to do it, it's just minimal changes to your existing code to get it to work):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var correctAnswers = 0;
var incorrectAnswers = 0;
var unansweredQuestions = 0;
var timeRemaining = 16;
var intervalID;
var indexQandA = 0;
var answered = false;
var correct;
    
    var start = $(".start").html("Start Game");
    start.on("click", startGame);
  $(".start-over").on("click", startGame);
    
var triviaQandA = [{
    question:"What is the fastest animal?",
    answer:["cheetah","turtle","giraffe","elephant"],
    correct:"0",
    image: ("assets/images/circle.png")
}, { 
    question:"When you are blue you turn?",
    answer:["red","green","blue","yellow"],
    correct:"1",
    image: ("assets/images/dot.jpg")
}];

function startGame() {
    $(".summary").hide();
    $(".start").hide();
    $(".timeRemaining").show();
    $(".question").show();
    $(".answers").show();
    $(".start-over").hide();
    correctAnswers = 0;
    incorrectAnswers = 0;
    unansweredQuestions = 0;
    loadQandA();
}

function loadQandA() {
    answer = [];
    answered = false;
    timeRemaining = 16;
    timer();
    intervalID = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    /*if (answered === false) {
        timer();
    }*/
    
    correct = triviaQandA[indexQandA].correct;
    var question = triviaQandA[indexQandA].question;
    $(".question").html(question);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        var answer = triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[i];
        $(".answers").append("<h4 class = answersAll id =" + i + ">" + answer + "</h4>");
    }

    $("h4").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if (id === correct) {
            answered = true;
            $(".question").text("The answer is: " + triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
            correctAnswer();
        } else {
            answered = true;
            $(".question").text("You chose: " + triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[id] + "    the correct answer is: " + triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
            incorrectAnswer();
        }
        console.log(correct);
    });
}

function timer() {
    if (timeRemaining === 0) {
        answered = true;
        //clearInterval(intervalID);
        $(".question").text("The correct answer is: " + triviaQandA[indexQandA].answer[correct]);
        unAnswered();
    } else if (answered === true) {
        //clearInterval(intervalID);
    } else {
        timeRemaining--;
        $(".timeRemaining").text("You have " + timeRemaining);
    }
}

function correctAnswer() {
    correctAnswers++;
    $(".timeRemaining").text("You are spot on!!!").css({
        "color": "#3d414f"
    });
    reset();
}

function incorrectAnswer() {
    incorrectAnswers++;
    $(".timeRemaining").text("You are sooo wrong").css({
        "color": "#3d414f"
    });
    reset();
}

function unAnswered() {
    unansweredQuestions++;
    $(".timeRemaining").text("You didn't choose anything...").css({
        "color": "#3d414f"
    });
    reset();
}

function reset() {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    $(".answersAll").remove();
    $(".answers").append("<img class=answerImage width='150' height='150' src='" + triviaQandA[indexQandA].image + "'>");
    indexQandA++;
    if (indexQandA < triviaQandA.length) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            loadQandA();
            $(".answerImage").remove();
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".summary").show();
            $(".question").hide();
            $(".timeRemaining").hide();
            $(".answers").hide();
            $(".start-over").show();
            $(".answerImage").remove();
            $(".summary").append("<h4 class = answersAll end>Correct answers: " + correctAnswers + "</h4>");
            $(".summary").append("<h4 class = answersAll end>Wrong answers: " + incorrectAnswers + "</h4>");
            $(".summary").append("<h4 class = answersAll end>Unanswered questions: " + unansweredQuestions + "</h4>");
            correctAnswers = 0;
            incorrectAnswers = 0;
            unansweredQuestions = 0;
            indexQandA=0;
            // setTimeout(function() {
            //     location.reload();
            // }, 5000);
    
            $(".start-over").html("Start Game");
            start.on("click", startGame);
        }, 2000);
    }
};

    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="start"></div>
    <h1>Trivia</h1>
    <h5 class="timeRemaining"></h5>
    <h3 class="question"></h3>
    <div class="answers"></div>
    <div class="summary"></div>
    <div class="start-over"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

There were 2 main problems with your code as it initially was:

- most seriously, you were adding `startGame` as the `click` handler for the "start over" button each time the `reset` function was called. As a result, multiple such handlers were getting added by the time you played a 3rd, 4th, 5th... time, with the result that the `startGame` function was getting called multiple times, which was why you were getting the answer options printed multiple times. I've fixed this by removing that section of code entirely, and adding the event listener once, on page load.
- your timer was also going a bit haywire, as you were calling the `timer` function manually as well as using `setInterval` to run it every second, and nor were you always clearing it when the question was answered. I've simplified this greatly, and made it work, just by setting the timer in `loadQandA`, as before, and clearing it in the `reset` function.

You will see that I've mainly just commented things out, rather than removed them - this will hopefully make it easier to see what I've removed.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but I still get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'correct' of undefined when the game starts again.  Have tried reseting the correct & answer variables to 0 as well with no success.

Comment: apologies, got the wrong variable name, I meant `indexQandA`. Apologies again, I'll update the answer.

Comment: just tried it with this fix. It's not working completely correctly, as the questions aren't getting shown on the second run through (the answers are though). But the error has gone. [EDIT: just figured out why this is happening, and added a suggested fix into my answer.]

Comment: Robin, you've got me sooo much closer! I appreciate it.... The only issue I have now is on the first & second times through it works great, but the 3rd time through it gets into an infinite loop and appends 2 sets of answers then starts looping the original errors in my console log... I've updated the html & JS on the codepen link.

Comment: That sounds strange, I'll take a look later when I get the chance.

Comment: That took me longer than I expected, there were a couple of other serious problems, at least one of which I didn't notice until I'd dug through the code a bit more. Please see the mammoth edit, including working code.

Comment: Robin, the only thing that I see left is 1 second before the timer loads into timerRemaining div the last Answer function text prints (ie "You are spot on", You are sooo wrong", etc.). I tried hiding/removing in the reset since I think it is due to the reset being 2 sec and timer being 1. Is there a way to fix that? The changes you made did fix all the other issues. Again, appreciate your help...

Comment: Hi @MissyB - thanks for spotting that, turned out I'd been a bit too overzealous in cleaning up your timer code. Just re-adding the initial call to `timer` before setting the interval did the job - I've edited the answer.

Comment: Robin, thanks so much again for the help! Works great! Let me know if there is something I need to do to close this out...

Comment: That's fine, happy to help - you don't "need" to do anything but it would be nice for you to upvote my answer since you found it helpful :)

Comment: I did check the green arrow for your answer. Thanks!